# How to pass pointer to struct to a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I am instantiating the struct within the `main()` function and I am passing a pointer to this structure over to a function. I would like to then pass this pointer to the original struct to another function, how would I do this?

I am now lost in pointerception.

```
struct coords {
    int x;
    int y;
}

// Main loop, instantiated the struct
int main(void)
{
    struct coords myCoords;
    while(1) {
        doStuff(&myCoords);
    }
}

// Calculate Coords and update them via pointer to struct
// I want to be able to edit myCoords within calculateCoords
void doStuff(struct coords* myCoords)
{
    calculateCoords(&myCoords);

    calculateMotorSpeeds(&myCoords);
}

// I want to be able to edit myCoords within here!
void calculateCoords(struct coords* myCoords)
{
    myCoords->x = 100;
}
```

Comment: `int main void() `..typo? should be `int main (void) `.

Comment: This is just pseudo code. But yes I will correct that.

Comment: `calculateCoords(&myCoords);   calculateMotorSpeeds(&myCoords);` remove `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `doStuff()` function, `myCoords` is already a pointer. You can simply pass that pointer itself to `calculateCoords()` and `calculateMotorSpeeds()` function.

Also, with a function prototype like

```
 void calculateCoords(struct coords* myCoords)
```

calling

```
 calculateCoords(&myCoords);
```

from `doStuff()` is wrong, as it is passing `struct coords**`.

**Solution:**

Keep your function signature for `calculateCoords()` intact, just chnage the call to

```
  calculateCoords(myCoords);
```

and then, any changes made to any member variable through `myCoords` inside `calculateCoords` will be reflected in the `myCoords` in `main()`.

Comment: Great, thats what I was thinking but was not sure.

Comment: @EricE `void calculateCoords(struct coords* myCoords)` is fine. just call it like ` calculateCoords(myCoords);`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the hasty help. I understand the use of pointers, but this threw me into pointerception.

Answer (score 1):

`doStuff` already has a pointer to your `struct coords` object.  It doesn't need to do anything in order to pass that pointer on to other functions.  So you can just define `doStuff` like this:

```
void doStuff(struct coords* myCoords)
{
    calculateCoords(&myCoords);
    calculateMotorSpeeds(&myCoords);
}
```

The reason why you needed to pass `&myCoords` to the call to `doStuff` in `main` is that there, the name `myCoords` refers to a `struct coords` object, not to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. myCoords is already a pointer so there is no need to use `calculateCoords(&myCoords)`. `calculateCoords(myCoords)` is enough.